# Tranfsorm an 8x4 Matrix into a 40x20 composed of 5x5 patterns

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I have to transform a 8 x 4 two-dimensional array of chars into a 40 x 20 two dimensional array of {0,1}, each cell of the original array is a letter from A to F, that repreents a cetain combination of {0,1) in a 5x5, it's kinda hard to describe so i'll just show you what i mean:

```
  F  D  A  E
  E  F  F  C
  A  A  C  C
  C  C  E  B
  B  B  B  A
  A  C  F  A
  A  C  C  B
  A  A  E  E

each letter represents a 5x5 array of given combination that looks for example like this(This is the "F" variant)

0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
```

After the transformation, the 40 x 20 array would be of type int and contain only {0,1}
Here's my code so far:

```
void MacierzSegmentow(char MacierzPosegmentowana[Wymiar8][Wymiar4])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            MacierzPosegmentowana[i][j] = char(rand() % 6 + 65);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I have little idea of how to do it.

Comment: Are you open to libraries? Eigen can do this without too much trouble.

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren This is a simple assignment to practice nested loops. Not sure, whether Eigen is appropriate for this at all. (Sounds a bit over-engineered.) And, I've serious doubts that OP is able to handle it.

Comment: I cant even use STL libraries for this project, it's a school one. After acquiring the 40x20 matrix ill have to make a dynamically created adjacency list, with vertices being adjacent if their are both "1" etc. This is just the first obstacle I've encountered in this project as i'm fairly new to programming.

Comment: How are the 5x5 matrices stored which corresponds to the characters `'A'` to `'F'`?

Comment: @KrzysiekDymanowski Ok, good to know the constraints and the context. There's no point in reinventing the wheel (Eigen is my go-to matrix library for not reinventing the wheel), but in this case it seems you're asked to that for learning purposes. This is still pretty open ended, do you need a "2D" matrix, or can you just throw in references to the blocks?

Comment: @Scheff I have to manually fill their patterns, as they are specified in the projects guidelines, That's also what im trying to figure out, I was thinking a simple function with a `switch ` that has 6 cases would solve it but really at the beginning of the thought process.

Comment: In what data structure are you storing the patterns for each char? I assume it's something like a 3D array, where each element is a 5x5 2D array?

Comment: @cigien The final outcome has to be a 40x20 2D array, the 5x5 patterns are also 2D arrays, however there maybe another way to accomplish what im trying to accomplish, if you are interested in the project as a whole I recomend you read my other post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66538196/how-to-search-a-big-graph-using-dfs

Comment: It's not about whether I care about your project as a whole. The issue is that this question needs to be self-contained. While a 3D array seems like a reasonable data structure to store the expanded 5x5 arrays for all the characters, it would be nice if you added that information to the question. It allows for more focused answers, and reduces the need for users to guess what you mean.

Comment: @cigien Excuse me, that was unprofessional of me. Going back to this question, I can't really imagine how a 3D structure like that would work and I don't think it is needed here, I just need to create a 40x20 2D array based off of the 8x4 2D array. I can't use stl libs(they are forbidden for this task), so What I'm asking is there a way to perhaps solve this problem using only well constructed `for` commands etc

Comment: It seems pretty easy, you need a way to convert the corrdinates of a point in the 8x4 array into the starting corrdinate of the equivalent point in the 40x20 array.  And then you need a way to "draw" the requisite character into the location.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Thanks Jerry, however I do not understand what you mean by that, could you explain it a bit more or give me some sample code?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question, but for each of the characters `A` to `F`, where would you be storing the 5x5 array of 1s and 0s corresponding to it? i.e. when I see a `B` how do I know what to fill in to the 40x20 array?

Answer (score 0):

Assume the character data looks like:

```
#define CHAR_DATA_WIDTH  5
#define CHAR_DATA_HEIGHT 5
#define CHAR_DATA_SIZE   6
int character_data[CHAR_DATA_SIZE][CHAR_DATA_HEIGHT][CHAR_DATA_WIDTH] = {
    {...}, // data for 'A'
    {...}, // data for 'B'
    {...}, // data for 'C'
    {...}, // data for 'D'
    {...}, // data for 'E'
    {...}, // data for 'F'
};
```

Then, if your input and output looks like this:

```
#define INPUT_DATA_WIDTH  4
#define INPUT_DATA_HEIGHT 8
char input_data[INPUT_DATA_HEIGHT][INPUT_DATA_WIDTH] = {
  {'F',  'D',  'A',  'E'},
  {'E',  'F',  'F',  'C'},
  {'A',  'A',  'C',  'C'},
  {'C',  'C',  'E',  'B'},
  {'B',  'B',  'B',  'A'},
  {'A',  'C',  'F',  'A'},
  {'A',  'C',  'C',  'B'},
  {'A',  'A',  'E',  'E'},
};

#define OUTPUT_DATA_WIDTH  INPUT_DATA_WIDTH*CHAR_DATA_WIDTH
#define OUTPUT_DATA_HEIGHT INPUT_DATA_HEIGHT*CHAR_DATA_HEIGHT
int output_data[OUTPUT_DATA_HEIGHT][OUTPUT_DATA_WIDTH] = {};
```

Then you can use this to convert each character in the input one at a time:

```
void ConvertInputToOutput()
{
    for(int y=0;y<INPUT_DATA_HEIGHT;y++)
        for(int x=0;x<INPUT_DATA_WIDTH;x++)
            CopyCharacterToOutput(x*CHAR_DATA_WIDTH,y*CHAR_DATA_HEIGHT,input_data[y][x]);
}
```

The first two parameters to CopyCharacterToOutput are the location in the output data where the character data should be placed.  The third parameter is the character to put into the output at that location.

And you can use this to copy the appropriate character data to the output:

```
void CopyCharacterToOutput(int start_x, int start_y, char character)
{
    for(int y=0;y<CHAR_DATA_HEIGHT;y++)
        for(int x=0;x<CHAR_DATA_WIDTH;x++)
            output_data[y+start_y][x+start_x] = character_data[character-'A'][y][x];
}
```

The output_data needs to be offset by the start location and the character passed in needs to be converted from a character to an array index.

Putting it all together, we get this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHAR_DATA_WIDTH  5
#define CHAR_DATA_HEIGHT 5
#define CHAR_DATA_SIZE   6
int character_data[CHAR_DATA_SIZE][CHAR_DATA_HEIGHT][CHAR_DATA_WIDTH] = {
    // A
    {
        {0,1,1,1,0},
        {1,0,0,0,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,1},
    },
    // B
    {
        {1,1,1,1,0},
        {1,0,0,0,1},
        {1,1,1,1,0},
        {1,0,0,0,1},
        {1,1,1,1,0},
    },
    // C
    {
        {0,1,1,1,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0},
        {1,0,0,0,0},
        {1,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,1,1,1},
    },
    // D
    {
        {1,1,1,1,0},
        {1,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,1},
        {1,1,1,1,0},
    },
    // E
    {
        {1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0},
        {1,1,1,1,0},
        {1,0,0,0,0},
        {1,1,1,1,1},
    },
    // F
    {
        {1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0},
        {1,1,1,1,0},
        {1,0,0,0,0},
        {1,0,0,0,0},
    },
};

#define INPUT_DATA_WIDTH  4
#define INPUT_DATA_HEIGHT 8
char input_data[INPUT_DATA_HEIGHT][INPUT_DATA_WIDTH] = {
  {'F',  'D',  'A',  'E'},
  {'E',  'F',  'F',  'C'},
  {'A',  'A',  'C',  'C'},
  {'C',  'C',  'E',  'B'},
  {'B',  'B',  'B',  'A'},
  {'A',  'C',  'F',  'A'},
  {'A',  'C',  'C',  'B'},
  {'A',  'A',  'E',  'E'},
};

#define OUTPUT_DATA_WIDTH  INPUT_DATA_WIDTH*CHAR_DATA_WIDTH
#define OUTPUT_DATA_HEIGHT INPUT_DATA_HEIGHT*CHAR_DATA_HEIGHT
int output_data[OUTPUT_DATA_HEIGHT][OUTPUT_DATA_WIDTH] = {};

void CopyCharacterToOutput(int start_x, int start_y, char character)
{
    for(int y=0;y<CHAR_DATA_HEIGHT;y++)
        for(int x=0;x<CHAR_DATA_WIDTH;x++)
            output_data[y+start_y][x+start_x] = character_data[character-'A'][y][x];
}

void ConvertInputToOutput()
{
    for(int y=0;y<INPUT_DATA_HEIGHT;y++)
        for(int x=0;x<INPUT_DATA_WIDTH;x++)
            CopyCharacterToOutput(x*CHAR_DATA_WIDTH,y*CHAR_DATA_HEIGHT,input_data[y][x]);
}

void PrintInput()
{
    printf("Input: \n\n");
    for(int y=0;y<INPUT_DATA_HEIGHT;y++)
    {
        printf("  ");
        for(int x=0;x<INPUT_DATA_WIDTH;x++)
            printf(" %c",input_data[y][x]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void PrintOutput()
{
    printf("Output: \n");
    for(int y=0;y<OUTPUT_DATA_HEIGHT;y++)
    {
        if (y%CHAR_DATA_HEIGHT == 0)
            printf("\n");
        printf("  ");
        for(int x=0;x<OUTPUT_DATA_WIDTH;x++)
        {
            if (x%CHAR_DATA_WIDTH == 0)
                printf(" ");
            printf(" %d",output_data[y][x]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    PrintInput();
    ConvertInputToOutput();
    PrintOutput();

    return 0;
}
```

Try it at https://onlinegdb.com/HyLwVkw7u

Comment: Hi. thank you very much for your answer. I will try to implement your solution to my problem into my program have a nice day!